# Show that there is at least one real number x such that f(x) = 0.

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and that $f(x)$ approaches $-3$ as $x$ approaches $-\infty$ and $f(x)$ approaches $17$ as $x$ approaches $+\infty$.

Show that there is at least one real number $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Look up Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Assuming $f(x)=0$ never happens then $f(x)$ is never near zero but to get from $-3$ to $17$ you need to cross zero(an unformal very loose argument).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post. ref: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4932/290189

Answer (score 3):

A rigorous proof should be as follows ...

Since $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-3$, there exists $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\le a\implies f(x)\in[-3-1,-3+1]$ (by choosing $\epsilon=1$ in the definition of a limit).

In particular, we have $f(a)<0$.

Similarly, since $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=17$, there exists $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\ge b\implies f(x)\in[17-1,17+1]$

In particular, we have $f(b)>0$.

It remains to apply the IVT to $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$.